# Exclude recoverable items folder from New-ComplianceSearch

Tags: powershell, office365

I am using Office 365's Security & Compliance Center to preform a ComplianceSearch and delete the offending emails using a Soft Delete. Once that is completed, I preform the same search to confirm that the emails were removed, but see the same number of results for my search query. This is because a Soft Delete moves the emails to the Recoverable Items folder. My question is, how do I create a `New-ComplianceSearch` while excluding the Recoverable Items folder?

**UPDATE**
Matthew pointed me in the right direction below. Using the script [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-Content-Search-in-Office-365-for-targeted-collections-e3cbc79c-5e97-43d3-8371-9fbc398cd92e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#step1) (and below) you are able to get the FolderID of the Deletions, Recoverable Items, and Purges folders for a specified mailbox:

```
# Collect the target email address
$addressOrSite = Read-Host "Enter an email address"

# Authenticate with Exchange Online and the Security & Complaince Center (Exchange Online Protection - EOP)
if (!$credentials)
{
    $credentials = Get-Credential
}

if ($addressOrSite.IndexOf("@") -ige 0)
{
    # List the folder Ids for the target mailbox
    $emailAddress = $addressOrSite

    # Authenticate with Exchange Online
    if (!$ExoSession)
    {
        $ExoSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $credentials -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
        Import-PSSession $ExoSession -AllowClobber -DisableNameChecking
    }

    $folderQueries = @()
    $folderStatistics = Get-MailboxFolderStatistics $emailAddress
    foreach ($folderStatistic in $folderStatistics)
    {
        $folderId = $folderStatistic.FolderId;
        $folderPath = $folderStatistic.FolderPath;

        $encoding= [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("us-ascii")
        $nibbler= $encoding.GetBytes("0123456789ABCDEF");
        $folderIdBytes = [Convert]::FromBase64String($folderId);
        $indexIdBytes = New-Object byte[] 48;
        $indexIdIdx=0;
        $folderIdBytes | select -skip 23 -First 24 | %{$indexIdBytes[$indexIdIdx++]=$nibbler[$_ -shr 4];$indexIdBytes[$indexIdIdx++]=$nibbler[$_ -band 0xF]}
        $folderQuery = "folderid:$($encoding.GetString($indexIdBytes))";

        $folderStat = New-Object PSObject
        Add-Member -InputObject $folderStat -MemberType NoteProperty -Name FolderPath -Value $folderPath
        Add-Member -InputObject $folderStat -MemberType NoteProperty -Name FolderQuery -Value $folderQuery

        $folderQueries += $folderStat
    }
    Write-Host "-----Exchange Folders-----"
    $folderQueries |ft
}
```

You can then use those FolderIDs to remove the folders from your search. For example:

```
New-ComplianceSearch -Name test123 -ExchangeLocation user@mycompany.com -ContentMatchQuery "subject:'some subject' AND NOT ((folderid:3F4BE1AEF6C6BB45B8F8EEFE472A7E5C0000000001130000) OR (folderid:3F4BE1AEF6C6BB45B8F8EEFE472A7E5C0000000001140000) OR (folderid:3F4BE1AEF6C6BB45B8F8EEFE472A7E5C0000000001160000))"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to excluding folders from a Security & Compliance Center is the FolderID property.  You can find documentation on this and other properties at this site:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyword-queries-and-search-conditions-for-Content-Search-c4639c2e-7223-4302-8e0d-b6e10f1c3be3?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

If you search for FolderID in that link, you will find another link to a document on how to obtain the FolderIDs for a specific mailbox, including PowerShell code to do it.  That link is:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-Content-Search-in-Office-365-for-targeted-collections-e3cbc79c-5e97-43d3-8371-9fbc398cd92e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#step1

What you are trying to do, exclude the Recoverable Items, actually involves excluding four separate folders:

```
/Recoverable Items
/Deletions
/Purges
/Versions
```

Each of those folders will have an associated FolderID.  Using the values from the second link above as an example...

```
/Recoverable Items  folderid:FDB58AF45BAF2F4A8CFD98F5396C6EB0000000001140000
/Deletions          folderid:FDB58AF45BAF2F4A8CFD98F5396C6EB0000000001150000
/Purges             folderid:FDB58AF45BAF2F4A8CFD98F5396C6EB0000000001170000
/Versions           folderid:FDB58AF45BAF2F4A8CFD98F5396C6EB0000000001160000
```

...you can append something like this to your Keyword Search in order to exclude those folders:

```
NOT ((folderid:FDB58AF45BAF2F4A8CFD98F5396C6EB0000000001140000) OR (folderid:FDB58AF45BAF2F4A8CFD98F5396C6EB0000000001150000) OR (folderid:FDB58AF45BAF2F4A8CFD98F5396C6EB0000000001170000) OR (folderid:FDB58AF45BAF2F4A8CFD98F5396C6EB0000000001160000))
```

Of course, you'll have to retrieve the actual values of those four folders from each mailbox you want to do this for.  Also note that excluding a folder does **not** exclude its subfolders...you need to use the FolderID value for each folder and each subfolder you want to target for exclusion or inclusion.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this sounds promising. I'll look into it soon and hopefully come up with something, though that sounds like it'll take a bit of work. If you're curious, I'm making a PowerShell script to delete spam and malicious emails from every Mailbox in an O365 tenant: https://github.com/jdgregson/Delete-Emails-O365/blob/master/Delete-Emails.ps1. It's very effective so far, but there is that one problem of not being able to confirm that the emails were moved to a deleted items folder.